# Azure logic app's try-catch specific error capture does not work

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am creating an azure logic app workflow with try & catch scope to capture specific exception message happens in one of actions within try scope.

As per the documentation, I am filtering Failed status of result('try') but still getting generic message " An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded." even when I try to capture `body('Filter_array')?[0]?['error']?['message']`

I followed this article & azure documentation as well but no luck: https://www.tech-findings.com/2022/06/Exception-Handling-in-Logic-app.html

[image: response screencapture]

[image: steps followed as per documentation]

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results try to follow below process then you will get output as I got:

Firstly, I have taken trigger and initialized variable as:

[image]

Then I have used scope as below:

[image]

Then I have set variable as below to get error (using this scope as try):

[image]

Then I added another scope to catch with run after as below (Using this scope as Catch):

[image]

Then i filtered array as:

[image]

[image]

Then composed it as :

[image]

Output:

[image]

The Scope(Try) error is composed into Scope2(Catch) as below:
[image]

Try to follow above steps you will get output as I got, I guess this clears all your doubts.

Comment: How to fetch a message alone from the above code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825959/how-to-get-error-message-from-action-in-logic-app/75828031#75828031  you can follow this thread to get error message alone